# Merging two nested maps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have two nested maps and I have to merge these two maps such that if the keys are same then it should merge the inside maps else keep as it is.

```
Map<String, Map<String, int>> one = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, int>> two = new HashMap<>();

one.put("a", someMap1)
one.put("b", someMap2)
two.put("a", someMap3)

resultant mergedMap = (("a", mergeMap(someMap1, someMap3), ("b", someMap2));
```

If the keys are same this will merge map values. I have the mergeMap() method implemented with me. How can I implement it?

Comment: `Map<String, int>` ????

Comment: Did you try `Map.merge()`?

Comment: Yes it is Map<String, int> and mergeMap(someMap1, someMap3) does something like Map<String, Integer> mapOne = new HashMap<>();
mapOne.put('a', 2);
mapOne.put('b', 3);
Second map:
Map<String, Integer> mapTwo = new HashMap<>();
mapTwo.put('a', 5);
mapTwo.put('b', 6);
mapTwo.put('c', 4);

resultant map = (('a', 7), ('b', 9),('c', 4));

Comment: You can't have primitives in collections .... So `Map<String, int>` does not exist in Java

Answer (score 0):

How about this (completely untested):

```
static interface Merger<T> {
    T merge(T a, T b);
}

static class IntMerger implements Merger<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer merge(Integer a, Integer b) {
        //TODO How do you want to deal with 2 inner maps containing the same entry?
    }
}

static class MapMerger<V> implements Merger<Map<String, V>> {
    private final Merger<V> valueMerger;

    MapMerger(Merger<V> valueMerger) {
        this.valueMerger = valueMerger;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, V> merge(Map<String, V> a, Map<String, V> b) {
        Map<String, V> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.putAll(a);
        for(Entry<String, V> ent: b.entrySet()) {
            result.merge(key, val, (a,b)->valueMerger.merge(a,b))
        }
    }
}

public static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mergeMaps(
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapA,
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapB,) {
    return new MapMerger<>(new MapMerger<>(new IntMerger())).merge(mapA, mapB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility function to create nested Map's.

```
private static <K, V> Map<K, V> innerMerge(K key, V val, BiFunction<V, V, V> function) {
    HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.merge(key, val, function);
    return map;
}
```

Example

```
Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> groups = new HashMap<>();
groups.merge(groupId, innerMerge(innerGroupId, groupName, (v1, v2) -> v1), (v1, v2) -> {v1.putAll(v2); return v1;});
```

If you want Map Like below, use utility function again to merge.

```
Map<Long, Map<Long, Map<Long, String>>> groups = new HashMap<>();
// You could use utility function get multi level Map merge
groups.merge(groupId,
   innerMerge(innerGroupId,
      innerMerge(innerAnotherGroupId, groupName, 
      (v1, v2) -> v1 + "," + v2), 
   (v1, v2) -> {v1.putAll(v2); return v1;}),
(v1, v2) -> {v1.putAll(v2); return v1;});
```

Note: You should define your own BiFunction to manipulate the value for existing key.

For your purpose you could simply use `map1.putAll(map2)`, if your both map1 and map2 signatures are same.